# Disk unmount failing ; Unable to install Lion OSX. Ends with a kernel panic

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I have been trying to install Lion OSX but it fails with a kernel panic. I was trying to erase my disk and reinstall Snow Leopard as before, but the disk erase failed with an unmount failure error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This could simply be a failed hard drive. Have you tried repartitioning the drive rather than erasing it?